# Peek at DOCUMENT_ROOT on a live site without compromising security?

Tags: php, security

I have some code in a form mailer:

```
$t = date("U");
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "\ssfm\gdform_" . $t;
```

and I have reason to believe that on my clients GoDaddy server the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is wrong. However, how can I have a peek at that value on a live site without compromising security for that window?

Comment: if any one knowing he server doc root, its going to comprise the site, there are bigger issues to worry about.... email your self the variable, echo it inside html comment tags .. none of theses ideas came to you?

Comment: @Dagon, I could see that perspective. It's probably pretty similar on a lot of installations in fact. That makes a lot of sense. I mean a common installation for Windows is `D:\inetpub\wwwroot`.

Comment: how about: encrypt the DOCUMENT_ROOT value with public key and show it in a hidden field in the form, then grab the value and decrypt it offline? (sounds overkill though)

Comment: If you want a peak, just take a look at your public IP, and then only show the doc root for that IP.

Comment: @DaveChen, now that's an idea!

Comment: unless people using your internet are evil and can see your root via lan, D=

Comment: in that case, make it password protected with `.htaccess`

Comment: password-protecting a page is only necessary if you want to share access amongst a group of people/locations. Restricting to your IP is perfect for situations where only you need to view the page.

Comment: If it's IP restricted, people on your network (wifi included), can also access the page.

Comment: That is also very true. I'd assume everyone on your LAN would be part of your organization and on your side, but that's definitely something to consider because this is not always the case. @DaveChen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [this](http://www.whatsmyip.org/) you can fill in the blank for `your.external.IP.address`.

```
<?php if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] == your.external.IP.address)
    var_dump($_SERVER);
```

This will show for only your IP. Documentation on $_SERVER can be found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

Comment: +1, I find myself doing this for testing on the live site as well.

Comment: I have a lot of company-only things set up this way at work (such as our new website install script). I've tested it with Curl from another location just to be 100% sure it worked.

Comment: uhh, if it's `company-only`, why not use a vpn and allow only lan connections?

Comment: Because it's a small, local company and none of us know how to do that. That is a good idea though. I'll do some research on VPNs now. We also do virus/spyware removal on the same network though, so I'd have to limit it to certain IPs (which I'm sure can be done).